# 1054 Unknown column in where clause?

Tags: php, mysql

i am updating my table employer with the following details but it is showing above error while updating

```
  <?php  

      $name=$_POST['name'];
      $phone=$_POST['phone'];
      $lname=$_POST['lname'];
      $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE employer 
     SET name='.$name.', phone='.$phone.',lname='.$lanme.' 
      WHERE username=".$_SESSION['username']." ");
      ?>
```

Comment: That's not prepared statement really http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Comment: Prepare the statement as `"UPDATE employer 
     SET name=?, phone=?, lname=?  
      WHERE username=?"` and then bind your variables before executing

Comment: And learn [how and when to use string concatenation in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

Comment: yep but i didn't give everything code here everything works fine but the syntax of query is the problem i think can u give me the correct syntax

Answer (score -1):

Query Statement is not properly concatenated.  This is the issue:

```
 $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE employer 
     SET name='".$name."', phone='".$phone."',lname='".$lanme."' 
      WHERE username='".$_SESSION['username']."' ");
```

Comment: Still not prepared statement, use `query()` instead Ps. not my downvote

Comment: yes query statement is not properly concatenated now everything working fine

Comment: OK, so you've got that working.....now create a real prepared statement, using placeholders, and bind your variables